# Show image from SQL Server 2008 in datagridview C#

Tags: image, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I'm tired of searching for a solution. please help me.

I have a table with columns

- `p_id (int)`
- `p_name (varchar50)`
- `category (int)`
- `price (money)`
- `picture (Image)`

Insertion process works perfectly, it is also showing me my database records.. but it sow me my  filepath in gridview rather than show image...

Please help me... it is part of my project... and I don't know how to show retrieve image from database in Datagridview

I have done all my SQL connection work in Dall Class

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;    
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Image_task
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void insert_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int count;

                dall insert = new dall();

                int id = Convert.ToInt32(id_txt.Text);
                string name = name_txt.Text;
                int cat = Convert.ToInt32(cat_txt.Text);
                decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(price_txt.Text);
                string image=pic_txt.Text;
                count = insert.insrt_up_del("insert into product values('" + id + "','" + name + "','" + cat + "','" + price + "','" + image + "')");

                MessageBox.Show("Insert Successfully", "Successfull", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            insert_btn.Enabled=false;
        }    

        private void browse_txt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            insert_btn.Enabled = true;

            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Images     (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF,*.PNG,*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                pic_txt.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            }
        }

        private void search_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dall select = new dall();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = select.select("Select * from product");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            //DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            //img.DataPropertyName = "Picture";
            //img.Width = 200;
            //img.HeaderText = "Picture Column";
            //img.ReadOnly = true;
                //img.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;
            //dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dt,null);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: I have some values in my Database Table.. I want to show my values in DataGridView.. Everything works fine but not image... It show path of image instead of Image..

Answer (score 0):

use data adapter

```
DataAdapter da = new DataAdapter("Select * from product",youconnection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?